# UPLOAD a DOCUMENT BASED on the user LOGGED IN

Tags: php, sql

I have put together a script that allows users to upload and view documents, however, the problem I'm having is if one user uploads a document, ALL registered users can see it.. so I'm trying to base the document upload on the logged in user... see the code below:

uploadconfig.php

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
require("upload.php");
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder = "uploads/";
    move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder.$file);
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO upload( file, type, size, personalid) VALUES (select personalid FROM person where personalid='$username'),('$file', '$file_type', '$file_size') ") or die (mysqli_error($conn));

    if($sql){
    header("location:upload.php?msg0=Document upload successful.");

    }

else {

    header("location:upload.php?msg1=Document upload failed.");

    }


    }

    ?>
```

The reason I have 'required' the upload.php file is because the user session variable is in that file, and I thought by requiring that file, I'd be able to pass that variable through to my uploadconfig.php file. But instead of inserting the data, it throws me a syntax error near the SELECT statement within the INSERT statement.

Can anyone tell me why this error is being displayed?

And if you'd like me to upload any other file, please let me know.

Thanks,

Sohail.

Comment: where is your SELECT statement ?

Comment: I cant see any SELECT statements. What it the exact error, and yes, you will need to show the code in upload.php

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select personalid FROM person where personalid='sarif'),('index.php', 'applicati' at line 1

that's the error I get, the select statement is within the $sql variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I was getting a syntax error is because I constructed my SQL statement incorrectly.. see below for the changes:

BEFORE:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO upload(file, type, size, personalid) VALUES (select personalid FROM person where personalid='$username'),('$file', '$file_type', '$file_size') ") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
```

AFTER:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO upload (personalid, file, type, size) values ((select personalid from person where username='$username'), '$file', '$file_type', '$file_size')") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
```

Thankfully, it is all up and running now.

Sohail.

Answer (score 0):

Change your insert query like this:

```
INSERT INTO upload( file, type, size, personalid) select '$file', '$file_type', '$file_size', personalid FROM person where personalid='$username'
```

For yours:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO upload( file, type, size, personalid) select '$file', '$file_type', '$file_size', personalid FROM person where personalid='$username'") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: The same one as before, as follows:  
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select personalid FROM person where personalid='sarif'),('index.php', 'applicati' at line 1

Comment: I have tried that because I was using mysqli, so I knew I'd have to make a few alterations.

Comment: `select personalid FROM person where personalid='sarif'),('index.php'`? I think you haven't updated with what I have given you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95032/discussion-between-muhammad-sohail-arif-and-vijaya-sankar-n).

Comment: I tried again with your query, it doesn't throw any syntax error but it also doesn't insert anything into the database.